# Проблема с обновлением файлов на Digitalocean

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js, digitalocean

У клиента есть Nuxt JS и Node JS сайт на DigitalOcean. Он прислал мне файлы сайта для внесения изменений и загрузки их в DigitalOcean. Я внес все изменения и загрузил все файлы на сервер SFTP FileZilla, но сайт выглядит так же. Что мне следует сделать, чтобы изменения вступили в силу?

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что его следует адресовать в соответствующую техподдержку

Comment: я им тоже написал но не ответили